# Get New Primary Key Value Dynamically (Max Value + 1)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a procedure in SQL Server 2008, to get new primary key value (max value + 1) for any Table (Table Name will be the input parameter) ... my code is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SysGetNewPrimaryKey]
(@TableName AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @PrimaryKey AS NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @PrimaryKeyLength AS INT
DECLARE @MaxValue AS NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition AS NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE @_PKInfo TABLE
(
     DbName     NVARCHAR(128)
    ,OwnerName  NVARCHAR(128)
    ,TableName  NVARCHAR(128)
    ,ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
    ,KeySeq     INT
    ,PkName     NVARCHAR(128)
)

INSERT INTO @_PKInfo EXEC sp_Pkeys @TableName

SET @PrimaryKey = (SELECT ColumnName FROM @_PKInfo)
SET @PrimaryKeyLength = (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(@TableName),@PrimaryKey,'PRECISION'))

select @primaryKey, @PrimaryKeyLength

SET @sql = 'SET @MaxValueOUT = (SELECT (ISNULL(MAX(@PrimaryKeyIN), 1) + 1) FROM ' + quotename(@TableName) + ')'
SET @ParmDefinition = '@PrimaryKeyIN NVARCHAR(128),
                       @MaxValueOUT NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql 
@sql, 
@ParmDefinition,
@PrimaryKeyIN = @PrimaryKey,
@MaxValueOUT = @MaxValue OUTPUT

SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @PrimaryKeyLength) + @MaxValue, @PrimaryKeyLength)
END

GO
```

When I try to execute this procedure its giving following error:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CityCode' to data type int.

Please advice as what is the issue. Sample table could be:

### CityTab

CityCode nvarchar(10)
CityDesc nvarchar(250)

**EDIT PART: (After reviewing below comments)**

If I will make this column IDENTITY then try to run following script to understand my issue

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblCity](
[CityCode] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
[CityDesc] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
[CreationUser] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TblCity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
([CityCode] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,              ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY])
ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO TblCity (CityDesc, CreationUser) VALUES ('Jeddah', 'sa')
INSERT INTO TblCity (CityDesc, CreationUser) VALUES ('Riyadh', 'sa')
INSERT INTO TblCity (CityDesc, CreationUser) VALUES ('Dammam', 'sa')

SELECT * FROM TblCity

INSERT INTO TblCity (CityDesc, CreationUser) VALUES ('Taif', NULL) -- This statement raises ERROR
INSERT INTO TblCity (CityDesc, CreationUser) VALUES ('Taif', 'sa')

SELECT * FROM TblCity -- 4 is missing now
```

Best Regards

Zee Shan

Comment: For what possible purpose? Even if you fix the syntax problems here, what is the point of getting the "next" IDENTITY value before you actually run the insert? Because unless you insert first and then retrieve the value you generated, there is no guarantee that the "next" value will still be available by the time you do.

Comment: +1 For Aaron's suspicions... I have the same concerns.  If you're doing this because it isn't an IDENTITY, you should make it an identity, and let SQL Server worry about concurrency and consistency.  If it is already an identity value, and you want to know what the next generated identity value is for some reason other than trying to sneak it in manually (bad idea), use [`DBCC CHECKIDENT(YourTable, NORESEED)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx), which actually handles the scenario where the the most recent identities have been deleted or rolled back.

Comment: I already have an identity column in my table which would have to be used for some other purpose ... I was thinking to drop that other column to make this column as IDENTITY but there will be one issue as if due to any error record will not be inserted even then SQL Server will increase the value and there will be gaps in keys which could be an issue at the time of audit. Is there a way to reset the IDENTITY to previous value in case of any error?

Comment: What is the meaning of _previous value_? Alice inserts 1, Carol inserts 2, Bob tries 3, Ted inserts 4, Bob does a rollback. Now you have 1, 2 and 4. Do you want to do 3 next, then 5? What you really need is a new version of your auditor. They'll have a fit when they see how many values SQL Server 2012 can skip on a clean restart.

Comment: @HABO .. Lets take you example ... Alice inserts 1, Carol inserts 2, Bob tries 3 but SQL raises some error in insert statement. Bob corrects that error and inserts again. But it inserts with "4" not 3. I don't want to do 3 again if there is a 4 in table but in case of any error in insert statement it should reset to MAX Value. Try to run script in my question to further explain my issue

Comment: Are you certain that multiple users could never have active transactions at the same time performing inserts? Your script doesn't simulate a large user community being chased by an auditor with a pitchfork.

Comment: @HABO if I will lock the table at the time of insertion and CATCH the error to reset IDENTITY before releasing the table then I think it won't make an issue for other active transactions? .. plz advice

Comment: If it is acceptable to serialize access to the table then you can avoid multiple active transactions. Don't forget to consider other failures, e.g power, that might cause rollback during recovery. Using IDENTITY and then clubbing it to do something different just to satisfy someone who doesn't understand transactions still sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys I have decided to use IDENTITY column for Primary Key. As for resetting IDENTITY on error I will discuss it further with my manager/fellow members before implementing.

Thanks to all of u ... see ya

Best Regards

Zee Shan